# how to select top 5 max values in mytable

Tags: mysql

Please help me with Query in Mysql..
i am Having table contains lot of rows .now i want retrive the 5 rows from that table.

my requirement is top maximum  5 values in that table "column name is amount" i want select from that table.outof N records i need top max 5 records from table

Thanking you,

Answer (score 36):

Just order the rows by (descending) amount and take the top 5:

```
SELECT amount FROM mytable ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 5
```

Note that this will result in a full table scan unless you have an index on the `amount` column.  This could affect performance if the number of rows in the table is very large (i.e. many thousands).

Comment: Got a quick question here, how about if the top three users have the same 'amount' value? and rest are different and therefore i want to select top 7 (first three counts as one) and then the next 4?

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 5;`