# Querying for Top contributor using mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL database which I'm querying using PHP/HTML page.

My database is follows:

```
+--------+-----------------+
| userID | changes         |
+--------+-----------------+
| bharath| kernel patch    |   
| vinay  | server halt fix |
| rajiv  | spelling        |
| mary   | logic change    | 
| bharath| new code merge  |
+--------+-----------------+
```

and so on...

I have a number of developers making code changes.

How do I query mySQL database so that it displays the list of top 5 contributing developers in html as follows?

```
Developer  Changes
bharath    45
vinay      21
rajiv      17
mary       16
```

Comment: What are 45, 21, 17 and 16?  Sounds like you need a simple group by name with count order by count desc: `SELECT userID, count(1) FROM mytable ORDER BY count(1) DESC`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646748/how-to-select-top-5-max-values-in-mytable

Comment: these are the number of entries made by the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the top 5, you need to aggregate to get the count, then order by the count, and choose the top 5:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(*) AS Changes
FROM Yourtable
GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY Changes DESC
LIMIT 5;
```